# Different apps with the same name?

Tags: google-play, app-store, microsoft-store

Let's suppose that two developers each create their own app and each of them want to call it "nameApp". Can they both publish it on Apple App Store, Google Play Store and Microsoft Store?

In other words, is it possible to find **two or more different apps** with the **same name** on the well known app stores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure about Microsoft Store, but with Android and iOS apps are identified by app id. You can't have multiple apps with the same app id. The name string is more superficial, it isn't used as a unique key in the app stores - it's more of a visual thing client side.

EDIT: Looks like Google Play Store allows multiple apps to have same app name as long as they have a different app id. But iOS requires both app id and app name (but not display name) to be unique from other apps in the store.  That's probably also why you see so many apps with super long, specific names in the iOS store.

Comment: Adding to @drhr In iOS there are 2 important names, **App display Name** (Name that appears under the app icon on your home screen). This can be same for multiple apps. **App Name** (Name that appears in iTunes). This should be unique and apple will give you an error if you try to use already used name.

Answer (score 1):

There is a game on Google Play Store called Fantasy Heroes by Userjoy Technology Co. Ltd but on the Windows store it's called Fantasy Adventure

Comment: I think the original poster is asking whether apps can have the same name. Not whether an app is posted in two stores with different names.

Comment: Moreover, I would imagine that if the app could of had the same name across platforms, then it would have, which would lead me to believe that the Windows Store also has a restriction on two apps having the same name.